# What should be used instead of 'PTO' for contractors?

Tags: terminology, business-language

When a full-time employee takes time off from their job, they often send an email titled 'PTO Friday', for example. PTO meaning paid time off. However, contractors like myself don't get paid time off. We get paid hourly, so we don't get paid for the days we take off. What should I title my emails when I need a day off?

Comment: What phraseology does your contract use for your work time? Can you base something on that?  It might be more helpful if you can explain just what these emails are, is it just a quick note to let people know they won't be around? In which case you could just say 'Not available Friday'

Comment: If you title it PTO, your intent will be clear, and they likely won't care that you're not being paid for that day. You might alternatively say "Hungry Androider OOO on Friday," where OOO stands for "Out-Of Office."

Comment: @rajah9 my concern isn't that my coworkers think I'm getting paid or not, it's that my manager thinks that I think that this actually is paid time off lol! But yes, OOO would do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Since this is a workplace question, you might consider migrating to our sister site, http://workplace.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @TheHungryAndroider, 'OOO' is okay if your manager takes it professionally. Otherwise,'ooo' is an abbreviation for hugs, usually placed at the end of a letter or in text messaging!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our place of business uses [OOO](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ooo) for both contractors and full-time employees.

> An abbreviation for Out of Office, a phrase often used in professional contexts to indicate that someone is unavailable for work (usually because they are on vacation).

Your Subject line might be: *Hungry Androider OOO on Friday*.
This abbreviation avoids stating whether it is Paid Time Off.